# how to use a break statement in a JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to write a script to detect whether the number is a prime number or not. The function works on some numbers fine, surprisingly it prints the number 133 as a prime number which is false. I'm suspecting the problem is with my break statement, so please correct if that is the case.

Here is my code:

```
function prime(num){
    if (num == 1){console.log(num + " is not a prime number");}
    else if (num == 2){console.log(num + " is a prime number");}
    else if (num !==2 && num !==1){
        for (var i = 2; i<num;  i++ ){ // num = 7
            if (num % i == 0){
                console.log(num + " is a not prime number");
                break;
            }
            else{
                console.log(num + " is a prime number");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only know that the number is not prime when you have tested **all** the possible divisors. Your code decides that the number is not prime as soon as it finds only one that does not divide it evenly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your last output that the num is prime outside the for loop. If you don't do this you will always break out of the for loop on the first iteration.

```
function prime(num){
    if (num == 1){console.log(num + " is not a prime number");}
    else if (num == 2){console.log(num + " is a prime number");}
    else if (num !==2 && num !==1){
        for (var i = 2; i<num;  i++ ){ // num = 7
            if (num % i == 0){
                console.log(num + " is a not prime number");
                return;
            }
        }
        console.log(num + " is a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will print both the messages if it detects a non prime number. Use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Or Python's `for … else` :-)

Comment: when I input 133 in your function, it prints both true and false, as in it's a prime and not a prime number

Answer (score 1):

If you take out the second break statement, the code will work.
This is because the loop breaks if the if condition in the loop is false.

```
function prime(num){
        if (num == 1){console.log(num + " is not a prime number");}
        else if (num == 2){console.log(num + " is a prime number");}
        else if (num !==2 && num !==1){
        for (var i = 2; i<num;  i++ ){ // num = 7
            if (num % i == 0){
                console.log(num + " is not a prime number");
                return;
            }
        }
        console.log(num + " is a prime number");
    }
}
```

Here is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

So we know the `break` keyword exits the current loop. The way the logic is structured in your for loop, the `break` statement is ALWAYS reached during the first pass of the loop. This means your loop is only evaluated once (for i = 2) and only numbers greater than 2 get to this point in your program. Therefor, you will only ever correctly identify non-prime numbers that are multiples of 2.

We can fix this by `return`ing instead of breaking once we find a factor. If we've exhausted all possible factors, then we can print that the number is prime.

```
function prime(num){
    if (num == 1) {
        console.log(num + " is not a prime number");
        return;
    }

    if (num == 2) {
        console.log(num + " is a prime number");
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 2; i<num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0){
            console.log(num + " is a not prime number");
            return;
        }
    }

    // We never found a factor, which means this must be a prime number
    console.log(num + " is a prime number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function prime(num){
    var isprime=true;
    if (num == 1){console.log(num + " is not a prime number");}
    else if (num == 2){console.log(num + " is a prime number");}
    else {
        for (var i = 2; i<=num/2;  i++ ){ // num = 7

            if (num % i == 0){
                console.log(num + " is a not prime number");
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isprime)
        console.log(num + " is a prime number");
    }
}
```

> few suggestions:
>
> 1. you do not need to check `else if (num !==2 && num !==1)` because if num is not 1 or 2 it will automatically go to the else condition. a simple `else` will suffice.
> 2. in your for loop you need not check till `i<num`. Checking till `i<=num/2` should be enough as the largest factor a num can have is num/2